# Load class from a folder with an existing class loader

Tags: java, classloader

I create Bukkit-Plugins and I want to load a class dynamicly. I wrote this code:

```
private static Class<?> getClassFromFile(File folder, File file) {
    if (!folder.exists())
        return null;
    try {
        URL url = folder.toURL();
        URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };

        ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

        Class<?> cls = loader.loadClass(getNameWithoutExtension(file));
        return cls;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I must use the main class loader, for example ClassLoader cl;
How can I load the file "file" from the folder "folder" with this existing class loader?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very simple solution :D!

For all the other peoples out there:

Change

```
ClassLoader loader = new URLClassloader(urls);
```

to

```
URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls, cl);
```

Works fine for me!